# Why does the following variable not display in a Django template?

Tags: python, django

I have a variable, `result`, that I display in a Django template using:

```
{{ result }}
```

If I set `result = "fred"`, it displays fine.

However, if  I set `result = "fred\xbf"` it is not rendered in the web page.

Why is this? How can I get variables with these types of characters to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Python 2.x? Try prefixing your string with u. Try `result = u"fred\xbf"`.

Sometimes templates eat exceptions and in python 2 not everything is unicode by default.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.4. Thanks.